# MD5 есть ли расшифровка?

Tags: md5

Я понимаю что вопрос возможно сильно "обобщенный", и не относится на прямую к программированию, или построению кода, но все же задам.

Я хотел бы уточнить, есть ли прямая расшифровка md5 или нет? Кроме сервисов подборов, которые имеют большую базу данных, и способы расшифровать более-менее банальный пароль.

Просто слышал что широфровка md5 уже устарела, и не считается надежной. По этому я не понимаю, она теперь стала обратима, или всё дело в огромных базах которые сверяют хэш.

Comment: md5 не является шифром вообще. Это хеш, заведомо не обратимое преобразование. И да, сейчас считается не очень надежной по той причине, что google на суперкомпьютерах с использованием специальных алгоритмов удалось изменить исходное сообщение так, что его md5 остался не изменным. т.е. восстановить исходное сообщение невозможно. но затратив огромные ресурсы можно составить совершенно иное сообщение md5 от которого будет таким же

Comment: Есть функция, которая от любых данных получает значение длиной в 128 бит (16 байт). Т.е. сколько бы ни было исходных данных - 100 МБ, 100 ГБ, 100 ТБ - все равно будет 128 бит. Как вы думаете, возможна ли вообще однозначная обратная "расшифровка"?